# Should I put method calls in initialize when using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, idioms

I am building a Calendar object. It is important that I have both a date object and date as a string.

```
class Calendar

  def initialize(on, off, date_string)
    @on = on.to_i
    @off = off.to_i
    @date_string = date_string
  end
end
```

I have a method that converts the date to a date Object. How to do I handle that in initialize. Do I put in a dummy value and then call it later? Do I call it from inside initialize. What is more idiomatic Ruby?

Comment: You're likely going to want to have ```attr_accessors``` setup for this so you can read/write the attributes.

Comment: @Caley, I was planning on doing that as well. I'm kinda new to this, so I'm reading up on them to make sure I understand them.

Comment: Sure! Just making sure you didn't get this fixed and then run into an issue with undefined variables etc.

Comment: @Caley, (@on) and (@off) should never change. Should those be attr_reader only then? Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, and if you ever try something like ```c = Calendar.new("1", "2", "1/4/2011")``` and then try to set on or off with ```c.on = "10"``` you'll get an undefined method for on=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it right in the initializer like this:

```
class Calendar

  DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"

  def initialize(on, off, date_string)
    @on = on.to_i
    @off = off.to_i
    @date = Date.strptime(date_string, DATE_FORMAT)
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you also keep date_string so that I can use it later when printing to a webpage?

Comment: @NoahClark is this rails? If you're using rails you get a lot of helpers in ActiveSupport that make this easier.

Comment: @Caley, no it is Ruby + Sinatra. I could always use the ActiveSupport gem though.

Comment: @NoahClark Ok cool, just checking. You could still ```require ActiveSupport/time``` I  believe if you started getting into a lot of Date handling and wanted some of the helpers (or write you're own!). 

Edit: Sorry didn't notice you'd already said the activesupport gem :D

Comment: @NoahClark I might also save the initial string. But more likely, I'd store the base Date object and convert it to the appropriate format at the point of preparing it for presentation.

Answer (score 2):

The more object-oriented way is to convert as early as possible, and to keep the rich object (here: Date) inside your new object. You have perhaps to convert the given `date_or_string` into a date.

Implementation could be:

```
class Calendar
  def initialize(on, off, date_or_string)
    @on = on.to_i
    @off = off.to_i
    @date = convert_to_date(date_or_string)
  end

  def convert_to_date(date_or_string)
     ... # Implementation here
  end
end
```

Comment: need to call ```convert_to_date()``` in the constructor here instead of ```to_date```

Comment: One thing I like about calling out a separate method to do the date conversion is that it may make it easier to develop test code that exercises the date conversion logic in a more isolated way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try writing an assignment method:

```
def date=(date_string)
  @date = ...(date_string)
end
```

It may be useful to convert the others in a similar fashion if required, then declare the read accessors, if applicable:

```
attr_reader :on, :off, :date
```

In your constructor you'd simply exercise this:

```
def initialize(on, off, date_string)
  self.on = on
  self.off = off
  self.date = date_string
end
```

Comment: This also has the advantage of allowing the date conversion capability to be tested in a more isolated way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to have too much logic in your `initialize` method - it means less flexibility in how you create your object. For example, I'd have

```
class Calendar

  def self.new_using_strings(on_string, off_string, date_string)
    on = on_string.to_i # Or Integer(on_string)
    off = off_string.to_i # Or Integer(off_string)
    date = convert_to_date(date_string)
    new(on, off, date)
  end

  def self.convert_to_date(date_string)
    # Implementation goes here
  end

  def initialize(on, off, date)
    @on, @off, @date = on, off, date
  end
end
```

That way, if I want to create a `calendar` object using a date rather than a date string, then I can do that.

I haven't seen anyone else take that approach, however.